# Is it true that $ AB^TBA^T = BAA^TB^T $

Tags: linear-algebra

From this answer on Stats Stackexchange https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/353715/274404, I don't agree with the last part.

\begin{align}AB^TBA^T
&= \left(\left(AB^TBA^T\right)^T\right)^T \\
&= \left(BA^TAB^T\right)^T \\
&= B\left(BA^TA\right)^T \\
&= BAA^TB^T
\end{align}

If I consider that B is a square matrix and A is the identity matrix, it would imply that $ B^T B= B B^T$. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can make sense of that author's assertion is in the case that $Z$ is a **row vector**. For a row vector with mean vector $m$ the covariance matrix is $E\left[(Z-m)^T(Z-m)\right]$, so the covariance of $ZA^T$ is
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(ZA^T)=E \left[((Z-m)A^T)^T((Z-m)A^T)\right]&=E\left[A(Z-m)^T(Z-m)A^T\right]\\
&=AE\left[(Z-m)^T(Z-m)\right]A^T\\
&=A\operatorname{Cov}(Z)A^T.
\end{align}$$
So the assertion is correct but the proof is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is correct: the author of the linked answer was wrong. In fact, in that answer, if $AZ$ is a valid matrix-vector product, then $ZA^T$ doesn't make sense unless $Z$ is $1\times1$.